# Trouble in finding latitude value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, shapefile

I am a beginner to geodata processing in postgresql. When I use the command:

```
SELECT ST_X(geom) FROM public.vivoidship;
```

I get an error which says:

```
ERROR: Argument to ST_X() must have type POINT SQL state: XX000
```

Where am I making a mistake? Kindly point it out.

Comment: can you show the table structure? Use the command, `\d+ tablename` at the `psql` prompt. Example, `dvdrental=# \d+ actor;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have found the solution ,Since it is a polygon,SELECT ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)) FROM public.vivoidship;worked